# Change audio player style

Tags: audio

I want to change the WordPress audio player. I need to keep the prosses bar(timeline) and hide other stuff like play, stop, volume and etc.

When I use the control attribute in the audio tag, all controls appear. how to hide unnecessary control like play, stop,...?

```
<audio id="music" class="wp-audio-shortcode" preload="none" style="width: 100%;" controls=""> <source type="audio/mp3" src=".....mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: A good starting point: "[A CSS style guide for the default WordPress media player](https://www.cssigniter.com/css-style-guide-for-the-default-wordpress-media-player/)"